# What is difference between __va() and phys_to_virt()?

Tags: linux, memory-management, linux-kernel

What is difference between __va() and phys_to_virt() ,what is need of these two separate implementation for same purpose, any difference between these two?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

phys_to_virt and __va are preprocessor macros. phys_to_virt:

```
#if !defined(CONFIG_MMU)
#define virt_to_phys(address)   ((unsigned long)(address))
#define phys_to_virt(address)   ((void *)(address))
#else
#define virt_to_phys(address)   (__pa(address))
#define phys_to_virt(address)   (__va(address))
#endif
```

And __va

```
#define __va(x) ((void *)((unsigned long) (x)))
```

If CONFIG_MMU is not defined then are equals.

Comment: Can you please relate your answer with Arm architecture android kernel with flat memory model,please don't copy paste  code,please tell logic behind this.